# Test if an object is plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, markdown, r-plotly

this may be a fairly straight forward question.

I am wanting to test if an object is a plotly object or not. I would ideally be testing a `ggplotly()` object.

Is there any simple way to do this? I can't seem to find a function like;

```
> x <- ggplot()
> 
> is.ggplot(x)
[1] TRUE
```

If anyone could point me in the right dirction that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class(x)
```

returns

```
[1] "plotly"     "htmlwidget"
```

where `x` is created using `ggplotly`.

So how about something like:

```
"plotly" %in% class(x)
[1] TRUE
```

You could make it into a function `is.plotly`:

```
is.plotly <- function(x) {
  "plotly" %in% class(x)
}
```

Comment: Can also be written as `inherits(x, "plotly")`